# Retrieving model fields via Odoo XML-RPC API and false

Tags: java, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-14

I successfully retrieved models from "ir.models" and their fields "ir.model.fields" as [documented](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html) using a Java XML-RPC client. However, the `store` field of a model fields confuses me. It is often `false`, e.g. for fields of model `res.users` like `phone`, `email`, `zip` etc and only a few like `login` and `create_date` have it set to `true`. Is that intended? I mean - according to [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-fields) - `store=false` marks computed fields but I can still set `email` when creating a `res.users` record via the API.

Also, I wonder why unset field values are represented as `false` via XML-RPC. I cannot distinguish a `boolean` ttyped field value of `false` to its unset value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a interesting inheritance situation with `res.users`.

This model has an embedded partner by using `_inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}` notation in the model definition. In database you will have two tables: `res_users` and `res_partner`. The relation between them is made by foreign key `partner_id` in table `res_users`.

But on python side this inheritance will lead to a model `res.users` which will have all fields of `res.partner` model, too. And odoo is marking the `res.partner` fields for model `res.users` records as not stored, because they are stored in anothers models table.

For your examples, `login` and `create_date` are real `res.users` fields, so they are stored in `res_users` table. But `phone`, `email` and `zip` and many more are `res.partner` fields and stored in table `res_partner`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not read anything about inheritance in the documentation so far. Do you know a good resource to learn more about the odoo data model and inheritance? Can I get the inheritance info from XML-RPC API?

Comment: I usually use the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension). And i don't know if that is possible by using XMLRPC or JSONRPC.

Comment: To be complete: Found out that inheritance can be retrieved via a "ir.models" field `inherited_model_ids`.